# Transcend jetflash 64GB Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive

I have Transced jetflash 64GB with some information on it.

When I connect it to my XP with SP3 machine system prompts me to format disk.

However when connected to Win7 machine disk works and display disk content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What filesystem is on it? Chances are it is [exFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT), which has native support in 7 but not XP. The XP patch for support can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955704).